# Protecting local proprietary data in an Xamarin app

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I have a Xamarin.Forms app that uses a local SqLite database as its source for data. The data is proprietary, so I want to protect it so that if someone gets access to the database file, they would have to decrypt it to access the data.

I also want to limit the number of queries users can make against the database so that at a certain point they have to purchase the ability to use more of the data (in-app purchase).

I want to avoid making network calls as much as possible to minimize impact to the user's data plan and allow the app to work well in conditions where there is poor or no connectivity. So, I want the data stored in a local database (perhaps in SqLite).

I'm curious how different people would approach this problem to protect the data and at the same time minimize network usage.

Here is kind of what I was thinking (if it's possible):

1) Let the user download/install the app.

2) On first load, the app will upload a key based on the device id and the user's current purchase information. Then it will download a SqLite database file that has been encrypted using the uploaded key.

3) When the user reaches their limit of queries, the database file is deleted. If they purchase more data, then a new key is uploaded and a new encrypted database is downloaded to be used.

Thoughts? Is there a better way?

Comment: nice question, let's see what others will say, if the database is stored locally limiting the queries or deleting the database doesn't help much i think, the user can find a way to access the database without opening the app but decrypting the whole database should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 8/2/2018 - SQL Cipher is now free and easy to implement thanks to the greatness of Frank Krueger. sqlite-net (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) is the defacto sqlite library for Xamarin now (if you're still using the Sqlite.Net fork I recommend going back to sqlite-net as soon as possible as Sqlite.Net has been abandoned) and it now includes SQL Cipher support completely free of charge.**

---

As clb mentioned, SQLCipher is open source. So if you don't want to pay for the component you can download and build the source yourself, then wrap it for use in Xamarin. This is, admittedly, a technically challenging task.

If that's not an option, I would recommend two other options:

1. Reevaluate your need to store data locally. It's extremely unlikely that you need to transfer enough data to even cause a blip on a user's data plan. And between cellular and wifi, it's not that common anymore for users to be without a connection. It certainly does happen, and there are certain apps where this is very important, but you may have to make concessions if the data is that sensitive.
2. If you absolutely have to store the data locally, and you can't use SQLCipher, your last real option is to use a cryptography library and encrypt the data itself, rather than the database file. This is less than ideal, typically, for a variety of reasons, but it may be your last resort. PCL Crypt is a PCL capable crypto library that you can look into.

https://github.com/aarnott/pclcrypto

Comment: I don't know if it was closed source since 2015, but from their website: "SQLCipher for Xamarin is only available through our Commercial Edition licensing via the link below, or through the SQLCipher Enterprise program."

Comment: SQLCipher itself is open source (see here: https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher). SQLCipher for Xamarin is clearly not, and I clearly stated in my answer that in order to use it for Xamarin you have to pay for the component or wrap the open source library for Xamarin  yourself. However, since this answer SQL Cipher on Xamarin has become way more accessible and I'm going to update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest SQLCipher! It is a Component within Xamarin (http://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlcipher-for-xamarin-ios) but can also be built from source as it is Open Source (https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/open-source/)

That will totally secure your database :)

Comment: The Xamarin components are nice but at $499 per platform, that's a hefty price. Is there a free or cheaper option for Android, ios and Windows phone?